# Display Tooltip on MonthCalendar on specific BoldedDate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, events, tooltip

I am developing a project on windowsforms in visual studio by using c#. At some point, I am inserting a monthcalendar control, I am bolding some specific dates on it and I want to display a tooltip on mousehover during runtime, ONLY for those specific dates. Then by clicking that date, the user will be able to extract information or go to external website. Below my code so far for that secific form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Delfoi_Tourist_Guide
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public Form5(string data)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            linkLabel1.Text = data;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login_User.CheckStatus(this);
        }

        
        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime sp_event1 = new DateTime(2021, 09, 20);
            DateTime sp_event2 = new DateTime(2021, 09, 23);
            DateTime sp_event3 = new DateTime(2021, 09, 29);

            DateTime[] EventDates = { sp_event1, sp_event2, sp_event3 };
            monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = EventDates;
        }

        private void monthCalendar1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(monthCalendar1, "Please select the bolded dates for more information");
        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        { 
            linkLabel2.Text = e.Start.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty easy to attach a tooltip for the whole calendar but I can't find a way to do only for those specific bolded dates. I tried to search everywhere online but to no avail. Can I ask for your help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you move the Mouse pointer on a MonthCalendar, you get `WM_NCHITTEST` and `WM_SETCURSOR` messages. You can then send a `MCM_HITTEST` message to the MonthCalendard to determine whether the point is contained in a *date* area. In that case, you should get `MCHT_CALENDARDATE` as return value. The [MCHITTESTINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-mchittestinfo) struct will give detailed information about the *date element*. If it's a match, you can show a ToolTip where the cursor is positioned.

Comment: Note that `MCHITTESTINFO` also returns the 0-based Row and Column indexes (the control-specific coordinates) where the pointer is located. -- Of course you need to build a Custom Control to handle these messages.

Comment: I think you want to get rid of the mouse hover event. Tool tips appear by default on hover over certain controls. Those controls have a tooltip property, so you can set that property to whatever text you want. Mind you I am doing this from memory. I believe you have to create a Tooltip object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=net-5.0. So if your Calendar has a control with a tooltip property, you should be able to use that. I have no idea how you created your calendar.